# -PipelineVariable isnt working as intended

Tags: powershell

I have this script that changes services per a csv file input

```
Import-CSV .\SSAS_services.csv |
    ForEach-Object{
        Get-Service $_.Service -ComputerName $_.Server -PipelineVariable svc|
            Set-Service -Status $_.Task -StartupType $_.'Startup Type' -PassThru
    } |
    Select-Object MachineName, Name, Status, StartType, @{n='OldStatus';e={$svc.Status}}, @{n='OldStartType';e={$svc.StartType}} | 
    tee-object -FilePath '.\ChangeServices_LOG.txt' #-Append
```

```
Server,Service,Startup Type,Task
DCVPIM108,SQL Server Analysis Services (MSSQLSERVER),automatic,start
server2,"SQL Server Analysis Services (MSSQLSERVER), SQL Server Analysis Services (MSSQLSERVER) CEIP",Manual,stop
```

it works great, except for my `-PipelineVariable svc`is not working as intended. if a service was "stopped" and "Manual" before being changed to "running" and "automatic", it doesnt get the old values "stopped" and "Manual" for `OldStatus` and `OldStartType`

```
MachineName  : DCVPIM108
Name         : MSSQLServerOLAPService
Status       : Running
StartType    : Automatic
OldStatus    : Running
OldStartType : Automatic
```

why is that?

Comment: As far as I can see the only purpose of -pipelineVariable is to give some better alias to $_, and looks like it should be defined before For-Each. What if you just use $_ instead of $svc?

Comment: @MikeTwc $_ it does the same thing as $svc

Comment: @MikeTwc also if i put it before the foreach i get this: -PipelineVariable : The term '-PipelineVariable' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file

Comment: OK, but anyway, this problem is not about that parameter then. As far as I can see your OldStatus calculation is just duplicating Status, is that what you need?

Comment: Also, if you just run  this, are you getting same problem: Get-Service -PipelineVariable svc | select MachineName, Name, Status, StartType, @{n='OldStatus';e={$svc.Status}}, @{n='OldStartType';e={$svc.StartType}} -First 10

Comment: @MikeTwc no i want the old status meaning whatever status it is when i get-service, BEFORE setting the service.

Comment: @MikeTwc am i supposed to run that command before the foreach/csv import? i am not sure otherwise how i can modify my script to include that line...

Comment: Oh, nvm, I missed start-service, let me think about it

Comment: @Mike Twc ok thnx

Comment: Before `Set-Service` instead of `-pipelineVariable` can you not just assign the current pipeline to a variable? `$svc = $_`, e.g. `Get-Service $_.Service ComputerName $_.Server | % { $svc = $_; Set-Service -Status $_.Task StartupType $_.'Startup Type' -PassThru } | ...`

Comment: @Jacob let me try

Comment: @Jacob Set-Service : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Status'. The argument is null, empty, or an element of the
argument collection contains a null value. Supply a collection that does not contain any null values and then try the
command again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-PipelineVariable` / `-pv` common parameter only works:

- within a *single* pipeline.
- in *script blocks* in later segments *of the same pipeline*.

Since you're using it in a pipeline that is *nested* inside the `ForEach-Object` script block, the commands in the *outer* pipeline cannot use it.

However, I suggest restructuring your command so that you don't need a pipeline variable for `Get-Service` anymore.
Instead,

- `-PipelineVariable` `$csvRow` is used with `Import-Csv`, so that you can more easily refer to it even in nested pipelines (the alternative would be to define the variable explicitly at the start of the `ForEach-Object` script block as `$csvRow = $_`).
- `$svc` is then declared as an `-OutVariable`, so that the original service state is captured before `Set-Service` is called to change it.
- Getting a service, setting its startup type, and enriching the CSV-row object with additional information now all happen inside the `ForEach-Object` script block.

```
Import-CSV .\SSAS_services.csv -PipelineVariable csvRow | ForEach-Object {
  Get-Service -Name $csvRow.Service -ComputerName $csvRow.Server -OutVariable svc |
    Set-Service -Status $csvRow.Task -StartupType $csvRow.'Startup Type'
  $csvRow | Select-Object MachineName, Name, Status, StartType,
                          @{n='OldStatus';e={$svc.Status}},
                          @{n='OldStartType';e={$svc.StartType}}
} | Tee-object -FilePath '.\ChangeServices_LOG.txt'
```

Comment: Yep, based on this thread we have deduced that pipeline variable is modified with the next pipe, https://powershell.org/forums/topic/pipelinevariable-isnt-working-correctly/

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you want is to pass same object down the multiple pipes. I haven't use -PipeLineVariable much, but looks like it just creating a nicer alias for $_ . If you need to push something specific down the pipeline I guess you need to use write-ouput with custom object or hashtable. Below is a dummy sample, pushing down and modifying a hastable:

```
$services = "xagt" , "xbgm" , "XblGameSave"
$list = new-object System.Collections.ArrayList

$serv | foreach { 

    $svc =  Get-Service $_ ; Write-Output @{Name = $svc.Name; Stat=$svc.Status}

 } | foreach {$_.SomeNewItem = "new stuff"; $list.Add($_)}
```

But in your case one pipeline might be sufficient. Try something like that:

```
Import-CSV .\SSAS_services.csv | foreach  { 
  $old = Get-Service $_.Service;
  Set-Service -Name $_.Service -Status Running
  $new = Get-Service $_.Service;
  $data = $_.MachineName, $_.Service, $old.Status, $new.Status -join ","
  Write-Host $data
  $data >> Log.txt

  }
```

Comment: I see. It's a shame pipeline variable isnt doing wat I hoped it can. -join "," wat does join do in this output?

Comment: converts array to comma separated string (creates csv row)

Comment: question, Set-Service -Name $_.Service -Status Running this sets service to running, what about if the service is defined as stopped in the csv file? i have to set the service based on what is defined in the csv file

Comment: yeah, it's just quick and dirty sample. Use $_.Status instead of Running.

Comment: oh i see. Get-Service $_.Service; is there a way where i can add some regex to that in case there is a mispelling to the service in the csv file, but the get-service will be able to recognize which service was meant by matching as closely as possible? for example, i know there is a filter like this: get-service * sql *

Comment: sure, do smth like $svc = $_.Service -repace 'x', 'y' ; Get-Service $svc

Comment: so x would be $_.service and y would be the ACTUAL service $_server.get services?

Comment: No, it's just a sample. I assume $_.Service is some broken string, an you fix it with replace that supports regexp (x will be replaced with y). Do you have specific sample you need to fix with regexp?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183035/discussion-between-cataster-and-mike-twc).

Comment: A pipeline variable is more than syntactic sugar for `$_`: a given command's current output object is only ever available as `$_` in the _very next_ pipeline segment, whereas pipeline variables are available in _all_ subsequent segments, allowing you to "stash away" an earlier output object. In @Cataster's attempt that didn't work, because the pipeline variable is declared inside a pipeline nested inside the `ForEach-Object` script block, where the _outer_ pipeline cannot see it.